# Sequence of $0$’s and $1$’s without six consecutive identical blocks

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, combinatorics-on-words

> Let $S_n$ be the number of sequences of $n$ zeroes and ones such that the sequence does not contain six consecutive identical blocks of numbers. Show that $S_n$ tends to infinity as $n\to\infty$.

Since we just need to show $S_n$ tends to infinity, I think a rough estimate should be enough. I think I should consider arbitrarily long sequences of zeroes and ones that follow a particular form and that don't contain six consecutive identical blocks of numbers. Or maybe some recurrence relation involving $S_n$ with some base cases might do the trick. Let $T_n$ denote the set of binary strings counted by $S_n$. Then $T_i$ is the set of length i binary strings for $i < 6.$ $T_6$ only excludes the all zero and all one strings. I think $T_7$ just excludes $\{10^{(6)}, 0^{(6)}1, 0 1^{(6)}, 1^{(6)}0\}$ since we can only have a block of $1$ repeating $6$ times consecutively. Obviously for a string of length n, the maximum length of an identical block that repeats at least 6 times consecutively is $\lfloor \frac{n}6\rfloor$.

Comment: When does $S_n$ tend to infinity? For what n? Please clarify the question .

Comment: Is $010$ repeated six times an example of six consecutive identical blocks of numbers? Can the block size be one so that $111111$ is six consecutive copies of "$1$"?

Comment: There are only finitely many square free binary words. But [A028445](http://oeis.org/A028445) is the sequence of numbers of cube free binary words of length $n$.  I believe that the references contain proofs that this sequence grows exponentially, though I have not checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call a binary sequence *$n$-good* if it has both length $n$ and the desired property (i.e., it does not contain six consecutive identical blocks of numbers). Call a sequence *good* if it is $n$-good for any natural number $n$.

It suffices to show $S_{n} \geq \frac{3}{2}S_{n - 1}$ because this would imply $S_{n} \geq \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}$, and the right-hand side diverges. We proceed with induction for which the base case is clear.

Suppose $\frac{3}{2}S_{i - 1} \leq S_{i}$ for every index $i \leq n$. Combining all $n$ inequalities gives $S_{i} \leq \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n - i}S_{n}$. Consider the set of all $n$-good sequences. We can form $2S_{n}$ sequences by taking each $n$-good sequence and appending either a $0$ or $1$ to the end of the sequence.

Among the constructed $2S_{n}$ sequences, some will be $(n + 1)$-good and others won't be. For the sequences that aren't $(n + 1)$-good, you can take some $(n + 1 - 6x)$-good sequence and append some block of length $x$ exactly $6$ times for some $x \geq 1$ to construct that sequence. There are $2^{x}S_{n + 1 - 6x}$ such sequences. Summing over all possible values of $x$, the number of sequences of length $(n + 1)$ that are *not* $(n + 1)$-good is at most $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 2^{k} S_{n + 1 - 6k}$. However,

$$\sum_{k  = 1}^{\infty} 2^{k}S_{n + 1 - 6k}  \leq \sum_{k =1}^{\infty} 2^{k} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{6k - 1} S_{n} = \frac{192}{601} S_{n} < \frac{1}{2}S_{n},$$

where the sum of a geometric series formula was used. Taking a complement we see $S_{n + 1}$ is at most $\frac{3}{2}S_{n}$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

It is shown in [1, Theorem 7] that, on a binary alphabet, cube-free words have an exponential density. This implies that $S_n$ tends to infinity.

[1] F.-J. Brandenburg. Uniformly growing $k$-th power-free homomorphisms, *Theoret. Comput. Sci.* **23** (1983), 69–82.

Comment: The question is from an IMO shortlist. I don't think the answer should be too complicated.